# How to delete substring from string?

Tags: sed

I have a string:

```
09/May/2012:05:14:58 +0100
```

How to delete substring `58 +0100` from  string ?

```
 sed 's/\:[0-9][0-9] \+0100//'
```

Not work

Comment: echo "09/May/2012:05:14:58 +0100" | sed 's/\:[0-9][0-9] \+0100//' -- works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work:

```
echo "09/May/2012:05:14:58 +0100"|sed 's/\:[0-9][0-9] \+0100//'
```

Output:

```
09/May/2012:05:14
```

Comment: I tried it right away, but it does not work under linux mint 12 with bash. :(

Comment: If that precise command does not work on your Linux (either with or without a backslash before the plus, depending on the regex dialect), it has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If they're always in that format, you can just do:

```
s/:[^:]*$//
```

This basically gets rid of everything beyond (and including) the final `:` character (colon, followed by any number of characters that aren't a colon, to the end of the line).